# Como endereçar a notificação via firebase para um app?

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que precisa receber notificações do servidor *PHP*.

Consegui desenvolver um código que envia a mensagem, mas ela não é exibida na bandeja dos dispositivos. Acho que não estou usando a chaves corretas no *json*.

**Código:**

```
$fields = array(
    'to'=> 'USANDO A CHAVE DO SERVIDOR -TOKEN DA SEÇÃO CLOUDMESSAGING DO FIREBASE',   <-- È ISSO MESMO???

    array('notification' => array(
       array(
           'title' => 'Titulo Teste',
           'body' => 'Corpo da notificação'
       )
       )));

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,  <- USANDO A CHAVE DA API DA GUIA GERAL DO PROJETO. ESTÁ CERTO??
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

E o retorno é este:

```
{"multicast_id":6476377154595056432,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1547467018208139%00000000f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Mas nenhuma mensagem é exibida na bandeja de notificações dos dispositivos que tem o aplicativo instalado.

Quando envio via console do *Firebase*, a mensagem é exibida normalmente no `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` da minha rotina no Android.

Comment: O `to` serve para informar para qual grupo você quer enviar determinada notificação. Fiz um código há um tempo (https://packagist.org/packages/valdeirpsr/firebasemessaging-php) e que pode auxiliá-lo. P.S.: Você pode suprimir o `to`

Comment: `'to'=> 'TOKEN DO DISPOSITIVO'` como você pode ver [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), é para disparar a notificação para um dispositivo especifico.

Comment: @Valdeir Psr sua estrutura é grande demais para uso no meu projeto e também não uso o composer. Tentei omitir o TO no código como falaram, mas a mensagem não é enviada e o retorno e apenas a palavra to. Agradeço mais alguma ajuda.
Havia entendido que apenas omitindo o TO a mensagem seguiria para o APP ligado a  API_ACCESS_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Você irá precisar do seguinte:

1. Classe para fazer uma requisição no servidor e salvar o id do celular
2. Outra casse para receber a notificação.

Primeiro de faça os imports do Firebase no build.gradle (Module: app), partindo do pressuposto que já está usando o firebase no seu projeto, pois tem outros passos básicos necessários para funcionar (aqueles que o firebase te ensina a configurar quando vc cria o projeto no console):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

Será necessário esses seguintes parametros no seu manifest dentro da tag application (junto com a declaração das activitys).

```
<!--notificação -->
<service
    android:name=".FCM.FCMInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".FCM.FCMService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Em seguida será necessário criar as classes para o FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

FCMInstanceIdService.java: para gerar o token unico do aparelho. Esse grava token, é para gravar no meu servidor próprio, caso nao use apague esse metodo):

```
/**
 * Criado por Leonardo Figueiredo em 20/08/2018.
 */
public class FCMInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

public static String TAG = "FirebaseLog";
String refreshedToken;

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    gravaToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);
}

public void gravaToken() {
    TokenModel tokenModel = new TokenModel();
    tokenModel.setTokenDevice(refreshedToken);
    tokenModel.setSo("Android");

    Call<TokenModel> call = new RetrofitConfig().getApiCandidato().gravaToken(tokenModel.getTokenDevice(), tokenModel.getSo());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenModel>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TokenModel> call, Response<TokenModel> response) {
            //sucesso
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TokenModel> call, Throwable t) {
            //falha
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Agora será necessário a classe FCMService.java: será responsável por receber e tratar a notificação.

```
/**
 * Criado por Leonardo Figueiredo em 20/08/2018.
 */
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static String TAG = "FirebaseLog";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.v(TAG, "recebeu mensagem do firebase");

    //verifica se recebeu alguma notificacao
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String mensagem = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrincipalActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .setContentTitle(String.valueOf(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacao)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_color))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensagem))
                .setContentText(mensagem)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(99, builder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Menssagem: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
}
```

Agora basta ir no seu console do firebase, vá no menu Ampliar -> Cloud Messaging.
Caso deseje enviar diretamente pelo seu scrip, veja nesse link o passo a passo, para que automatize e envie pelo seu script: https://gist.github.com/rolinger/d6500d65128db95f004041c2b636753a

Preencha os dados e envie e seja feliz.

OBS.: Coloque um breakpoint na classe FCMInstanceIdService e verifique se ele gerou uma hash, esse é o id exclusivo do seu aparelho (só acontece na primeira vez que instala o App).

Antes de enviar coloque um breakpoint na classe FCMService, pois é nela que irá chegar a mensagem.